# Error: Cannot apply PATCH to navigation property. So what do I do?

Tags: c#, odata, asp.net-web-api2

I have a Web API 2.2 OData 4 service the following model using entity framework:

```
public class Company
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public virtual ICollection<CompanyType> CompanyTypes { get; set; }
}

public class CompanyType
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public virtual ICollection<Company> Companies { get; set; }
}
```

And a bit of fluent mapping:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Company>().HasMany(x => x.CompanyTypes).WithMany(x => x.Companies).Map(x =>
{
  x.MapLeftKey("CompanyId");
  x.MapRightKey("CompanyTypeId");
  x.ToTable("CompaniesCompanyTypes");
});
```

On my CompanysController I have a patch method and was hoping to be able to send the following request and successfuly update the company name and create a couple of company types records for that company:

```
PATCH http://localhost:50113/MessagingService/odata//CompanyDTOs(1)/ HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-16
Host: localhost:50113
Content-Length: 174

{"Name":"Cheesy Peas Ltd","CompanyTypes":[{"Id":1,"Name":"Parent"},{"Id":2,"Name":"Subsidiary"}]}
```

But I receive a:

```
{
  "error":{
    "code":"","message":"The request is invalid.","innererror":{
      "message":"delta : Cannot apply PATCH to navigation property 'CompanyTypes' on entity type 'Core.Models.Company'.\r\n","type":"","stacktrace":""
    }
  }
}
```

I assume that I'm asking too much of my PATCH request, but does anyone have a suggestion for how I should achieve this? The simpler the better - I'm not keen on adding complexity to my client application if I can avoid it and would prefer to use PATCH rather that PUT.

Thanks very much. If you're interested in this question and need more details, please ask.

**EDIT**

Specifically, what I'm after is to be able to insert a record in a many-to-many table when updating a record in a part of that relationship. Eg. If a Student has many Classes and a Class has many Students then when I update Student A I might also want to add a reference to Class One, delete a reference to Class Two and leave a reference to Class Three intact.

I've done some reading of the OData documentation here:

http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata-atom-format/v4.0/cs02/odata-atom-format-v4.0-cs02.html#_Toc372792732

But it's a bit of a mystery to me. I'm sure there must be a way of doing this using things like "@odata.bind" etc.

Any opinions out there?

Answer (score 4):

Based on [this workitem](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/562), you need to create a collection of primitive types instead of list complex type.

**Entity**

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ProductType> ProductTypes { get; set; }
}
public class ProductDto : Product
{
    public ICollection<int> ProductTypeIds { get; set; }
    public ICollection<string> ProductTypeNames { get; set; }
}
public class ProductType
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

**Action**

```
// PATCH odata/Products(5)
[AcceptVerbs("PATCH", "MERGE")]
public IHttpActionResult Patch([FromODataUri] int key, Delta<ProductDto> patch)
{
    object productTypeIds;
    patch.TryGetPropertyValue("ProductTypeIds", out productTypeIds);
    object productTypeNames;
    patch.TryGetPropertyValue("ProductTypeNames", out productTypeNames);

    // TODO: Implement update to database.

    return Updated(new ProductDto()); // for demo purpose
}
```

**Config**

```
ODataConventionModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
builder.EntitySet<Product>("Products");
builder.EntitySet<ProductDto>("ProductDtos");
builder.EntitySet<ProductType>("ProductType");
config.Routes.MapODataServiceRoute("odata", "odata", builder.GetEdmModel());
```

**Fiddler**

```
PATCH http://localhost:59829/odata/Products(1) HTTP/1.1

User-Agent: Fiddler
Host: localhost:59829
Content-Length: 83
Content-Type: application/json

{"Id":1, "Name":"A", "ProductTypeIds":[1,2], "ProductTypeNames":["AA", "BB"] }
```

**Result**

[image: Result]

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you @Yuliam. I can see that your solution would work but from the looking at that workitem it seems that it has already been fixed, doesn't it?

Comment: @user2363071, as far my understanding it's about nullable<T> and collection that has been fixed based on [the link](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/4a1dd862fbce) in the comment, for complex type itself, probably not, see another [workitem](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/2066)

Comment: Thanks very much. I'll switch to PUT for now and accept that I'll have to retrieve the entity from the database and merge my changes before I update (and risk dirty writes) and keep an eye out for the next version.

Comment: Should this still be done in this way in ASP.NET Core OData 2022 ? Currently PATCH simply ignores collections of non-primitive types. But doing it in this way is overkill. Can I somehow just put my collection into a property? :-)